# How to stop date changing at 00:00 o'clock?

Tags: java, date

I'm working on Hotel management application *[desktop]* and I noticed, the date changing time hotels system is not 00:00 am , it's between  **1AM** and  **6AM** so reservations  and room status etc. should be stay until audit time.When the user make audit the new day will start.

That's why I need to create a method that stop date change at midnight and return new date when audit button clicked. Briefly I have to create central system for date.

As a result; when I use this date in all classes every methods will work synchronously[blockade, reservations, check in,  check out etc.] but I couldn't find good way to do this.

I'm thinking around some code like this :

```
package com.coder.hms.utils;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class CustomDateFactory {

    private Date date;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf;

    public CustomDateFactory() {

        //for formatting date as desired
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

    public void setValidDateUntilAudit(int counter) {

        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //get hour and minute from calendar
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int sec = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                //check if the field value equals -1
                if (counter == -1) {
                    //and the time at 00:00
                    if (hour == 0 && min == 0 && sec == 2) {
                        //bring the date one day back
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, counter);
                        date = calendar.getTime();
                    }
                } else {
                    date = new Date();
                }

            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 100);
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        final String today = sdf.format(date);
        final LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(today);
        date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(ld);
        return date;
    }
}
```

After comments and helps I changed my code like this :

```
public class DateFactoryTest {

    private LocalDate currentDate;
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    public DateFactoryTest() {
        currentDate = LocalDate.now();
        localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    private void setTheDate(boolean isAuditted) {

        if (localDateTime.getHour() <= 6 && isAuditted == false) {

            currentDate.minusDays(1);

        } else if (localDateTime.getHour() > 6 && isAuditted == true) {

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/coder/hms/icons/dialogPane_question.png"));

            int choosedVal = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You're doing early audit, are you sure about this?",
                    "Approving question", 0, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, icon, null, null);

            if (choosedVal == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                isAuditted = false;
            }

        }

    }

    private LocalDate getDate() {
        return currentDate;
    }

}
```

All answers, different ideas acceptable.

Comment: Just get the date of `new Date()` - 6 hours (or whatever is appropriate). Besides that, I'm not sure I fully understand your requirement. Is the date forced to change after 6 am but not before 1 am? What would that "audit" mean in your case? And do you really want the user to take manual steps in the middle of the night?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for replay but the problem not that;  when the clock 00:00 everything change automatically because all application working with new Date() so I need to stop it before changing everything or after 1 second to all thing remain as old.

Comment: You might rethink how the application works then. Messing with the date just to get some logic done doesn't feel right and robust. Instead try to define points in time where a new period is starting, e.g. after 6 am or when the user clicked that audit button.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`. Now supplanted by the java.time classes. Among those obsolete classes is `java.sql.Date` – you may have to use it if your JDBC driver is not yet updated for JDBC 4.2 and later, but if so, minimize its use and do *not* use these objects in your business logic.

As other people commented, **do not hack the meaning of a date**. If a “Hotel Day” really runs from 6 AM to 6 AM, then create a class to represent that. Define a member for the official date, of type [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Define also members for the start and stop, of type [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), where the stop is `plusDays( 1 )`.

Define a pair of getter methods each taking a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) argument, and returning a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), each for the true exact moment when the hotel-day starts and stops. A `LocalDateTime` is not an actual moment, and has no meaning until you specify a time zone. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the 6 AM start or stop time might really be 5 AM or 7 AM or 6:15 AM on a particular date.

```
public startAtZone( ZoneId z ) {
    ZonedDateTime zdt = this.startLocalDateTime.atZone( z ) ;
    return zdt ; 
}
```

Calculate the span of time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Call the `to…` methods to get a total number of seconds, milliseconds, or nanoseconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( ZonedDateTime.now( z ) , myHotelDay.stopAtZone( z ) ) ;
```

Note that the best approach to defining spans of time is generally the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* and the ending is *exclusive*. This means your hotel-day starting at 6 AM runs up to, but does *not* include, the following 6 AM. **That means `6 AM to 6 AM`**, so no bothering to determine 05:59:59.999 or 05:59:59.999999 or 05:59:59.999999999. Search with `>= && <` logic, and do *not* use SQL `BETWEEN`.

By the way, `Timer` is legacy now. Read about the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework, and search Stack Overflow.

By the way, the format you used, `yyyy-MM-dd`, is defined by the ISO 8601 standard. The java.time classes use those standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: +1 for useful informations, I'm using java.sql.Date for getting formatted String as date [String -> Date] because always I'm getting parse exception with parsing, maybe there is another way easier and safer but I don't know.Any way Thanks.

Comment: @CoderACJHP There are many ways to parse dates like using `DateTimeFormatter`, just search a bit for it (`SimpleDateFormat` is outdated now). Here is a [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html).

Comment: @Zabuza I learned many things by asking this question :) .Actually I'm learning software development as a hobby that's why I can not follow innovations constantly with my job :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed my problem with changing logic of code.Now the code will not stop the date at 00:00 but it will return old date if Audit == false and the time < 6 and as same logic it's return current day date or old day date etc.

So far my code has been like this :

```
package com.coder.hms.utils;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CustomDateFactory {

    private LocalDate currentDate;
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
    private final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().
            getResource("/com/coder/hms/icons/dialogPane_question.png"));

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CustomDateFactory dateFactoryTest = new CustomDateFactory();
        dateFactoryTest.setValidDateUntilAudit(true);
        //for test
        String realDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
        System.out.println("REAL DATE : " + realDate);
        System.out.println("PREPARED DATE : " + dateFactoryTest.getDate());


    }

    public CustomDateFactory() {

        localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    private void setValidDateUntilAudit(boolean isAuditted) {

        if (localDateTime.getHour() <= 6 && isAuditted == false) {
            currentDate = LocalDate.now();
            currentDate = currentDate.minusDays(1);

        }

        else if(localDateTime.getHour() < 6 && isAuditted == true) {

            int choosedVal = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You're doing early audit, are you sure about this?",
                    "Approving question", 0, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, icon, null, null);

            if (choosedVal == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                currentDate = LocalDate.now();
                isAuditted = false;
            }
            else {
                currentDate = LocalDate.now();
                currentDate = currentDate.minusDays(1);

            }

        } 

        else if (localDateTime.getHour() > 6 && isAuditted == true) {

            int choosedVal = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Are you sure about this?",
                    "Approving question", 0, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, icon, null, null);

            if (choosedVal == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                currentDate = LocalDate.now();
                isAuditted = false;
            }
            else {
                currentDate = LocalDate.now();
                currentDate = currentDate.minusDays(1);
                isAuditted = false;
            }

        }

    }

    private LocalDate getDate() {
        return currentDate;
    }

}
```

Thanks for all.